# Do symmetric monoidal functors preserve reflexivity?

Tags: category-theory, topological-vector-spaces, duality-theorems, monoidal-categories, reflexive-space

Suppose that $(C, \otimes_C, \mathcal{H}om_C, I_C), (D, \otimes_D, \mathcal{H}om_D, I_D)$ are closed symmetric monoidal categories. Let
$$
F: (C, \otimes_C,  I_C) \rightarrow (D, \otimes_D,  I_D)
$$
be a (strong) symmetric monoidal functor, i.e. $F(X \otimes_C Y) \cong F(X) \otimes_D F(Y)$
and $F(I_C) \cong I_D$.
Then $F$ preserves *strongly* dualizable objects, but in general, it is not true that $F$ preserves internal homs and hence in general $F$ does not preserve weak duals, i.e. $F(X^\vee) \not\cong F(X)^\vee$, where $X^\vee:=\mathcal{H}om(X, I_C)$ is a weak dual.

Next, suppose further that $(C, \otimes_C, \mathcal{H}om_C, I_C)$ is $*$-autonomous, i.e. has a global dualizing object $G$. Namely, if we set $A^\vee: = \mathcal{H}om_C(A, G)$, then the canonical map
$$
A \rightarrow (A^\vee)^\vee
$$
is an isomorphism.

**Question:** Is it true that $F(G)$ is a global dualizing object for $(D, \otimes_D, \mathcal{H}om_D, I_D)$, making this category also $*$-autonomous? Alternatively, is the essential image of $F$ $*$-autonomous, i.e. is
$$
F(A) \rightarrow (F(A)^\vee)^\vee
$$
an isomorphism for all objects $A$ in $C$? Here, $F(A)^\vee:= \mathcal{H}om_D(F(A), F(G))$.

**Note**
I know that certain categories of topological vector spaces are $*$-autonomous with respect to internal hom given by continuous linear maps: https://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/tvs.pdf
On the other hand, the category of (infinite-dimensional) vector spaces is not $*$-autonomous, as it fails the condition $A\rightarrow (A^\vee)^\vee$. I thought that the forgetful functor that takes a topological vector space to the underlying discrete vector space would answer the above question, but in fact this functor is *not* strongly symmetric monoidal since the tensor product of topological vector spaces is a quotient of the algebraic tensor product. But maybe a similar example works?